# How can I make a border color stay the same when interacting with input type="number"?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple timer, and I've just about got the styling the way I want. I plan adding the ability for the user to specify the number of hours, minutes, and seconds they want to set the timer.

My issue arises when I go into the `input type=number` element to change the number. The border-color is green when these elements aren't being used; however, once I click those elements, the border changes to black. How can I make it stay the same?

```css
body{
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 25px;
}

.timer{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 24px 32px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: white;
}

.timer__btn{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: white;
    background: #CC02DD;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.timer__btn--start{
    background: #00b84c;
}

.timer__btn--stop{
    background: #ff0256;
}

.timer__part{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.number__select{
    width: 60px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #009900;
    text-align: center;
}

/* .number__select{
    border-color: #009900;
} */

.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-variation-settings:'FILL' 1,'wght' 400,'GRAD' 0,'opsz' 48;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    <script src="countdown.js"></script>
    <title>Countdown Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="timer">
        <span class="timer__part timer__part--hours">00</span>
        <span class="timer__part">:</span>
        <span class="timer__part timer__part--minutes">00</span>
        <span class="timer__part">:</span>
        <span class="timer__part timer__part--seconds">00</span>
        <button type="button" class="timer__btn timer__btn--control timer__btn--start">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                play_arrow
            </span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="timer__btn timer__btn--reset">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                restart_alt
            </span>
        </button>
        <div class="time__select">
            <input type="number" class="number__select" min="1" max="99">
            <input type="number" class="number__select" min="1" max="59">
            <input type="number" class="number__select" min="1" max="59"> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add outline:none; to your input's style

Answer (score 0):

**simply add outline color same as border**  or * Remove outline

```css
body{
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 25px;
}

.timer{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 24px 32px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: white;
}

.timer__btn{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: white;
    background: #CC02DD;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.timer__btn--start{
    background: #00b84c;
}

.timer__btn--stop{
    background: #ff0256;
}

.timer__part{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.number__select{
    width: 60px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #009900;
    outline:#009900;             **//Simply add outline**
    text-align: center;
}


/* .number__select{
    border-color: #009900;
} */

.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-variation-settings:'FILL' 1,'wght' 400,'GRAD' 0,'opsz' 48;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    <script src="countdown.js"></script>
    <title>Countdown Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="timer">
        <span class="timer__part timer__part--hours">00</span>
        <span class="timer__part">:</span>
        <span class="timer__part timer__part--minutes">00</span>
        <span class="timer__part">:</span>
        <span class="timer__part timer__part--seconds">00</span>
        <button type="button" class="timer__btn timer__btn--control timer__btn--start">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                play_arrow
            </span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="timer__btn timer__btn--reset">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                restart_alt
            </span>
        </button>
        <div class="time__select">
            <input type="number" class="number__select" min="1" max="99">
            <input type="number" class="number__select" min="1" max="59">
            <input type="number" class="number__select" min="1" max="59"> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the element's outline to none

```
.number__select{ outline: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 25px;
}

.timer{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 24px 32px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: white;
}

.timer__btn{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: white;
    background: #CC02DD;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.timer__btn--start{
    background: #00b84c;
}

.timer__btn--stop{
    background: #ff0256;
}

.timer__part{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.number__select{
    width: 60px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #009900;
    text-align: center;
}

 .number__select{
    outline:none;
} 

.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-variation-settings:'FILL' 1,'wght' 400,'GRAD' 0,'opsz' 48;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    <script src="countdown.js"></script>
    <title>Countdown Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="timer">
        <span class="timer__part timer__part--hours">00</span>
        <span class="timer__part">:</span>
        <span class="timer__part timer__part--minutes">00</span>
        <span class="timer__part">:</span>
        <span class="timer__part timer__part--seconds">00</span>
        <button type="button" class="timer__btn timer__btn--control timer__btn--start">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                play_arrow
            </span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="timer__btn timer__btn--reset">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                restart_alt
            </span>
        </button>
        <div class="time__select">
            <input type="number" class="number__select" min="1" max="99">
            <input type="number" class="number__select" min="1" max="59">
            <input type="number" class="number__select" min="1" max="59"> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Introduction to the outline property

- The outline will appear every time you click the element with outline.
- The outline property default value will make it appear.

To make the outline disappear, use `outline: none;`

***Note:*** **The commented code is uncommented and edited.**